# Error using C# Parameter @id has no default value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oledbexception

I created a login form in asp, and I seem to get this error:

> ```
> Parameter @id has no default value.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the >current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> ```
>
> information about >the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> ```
> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Parameter @id has no >default value.
>
> Source Error: 
>
>
> Line 18:         });
> Line 19: 
>
> Line 20:         OleDbDataReader reader = loginCommand.ExecuteReader();
> Line 21:         if (reader.Read())
> Line 22:         {
> ```

```
    OleDbConnection connection = new 
    OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + 
    Server.MapPath("\\App_Data\\talManager.mdb"));
    connection.Open();

    OleDbCommand loginCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    loginCommand.Connection = connection;
    loginCommand.CommandText = "SELECT [_fname], [_id], [_password] FROM 
    admins WHERE [_id] = @id AND [_password] = @password";
    loginCommand.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
    {
        new OleDbParameter("@id", Request.Form["id"]),
        new OleDbParameter("@password", Request.Form["password"])
    });

OleDbDataReader reader = loginCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
    Session["fname"] = reader["_fname"];
    Session["id"] = reader["_id"];
    Session["isAdmin"] = true;
} else
{
    error.InnerText = "Invalid ID or password.";
}

reader.Close();
connection.Close();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for the bad format, I got lost in the editor :D

Comment: Well, [edit] and fix.  Also, debug and look at the value of `Request.Form["id"]),`  Is it empty? Why?

Comment: are you sure that Request.Form["id"] is not null?

Comment: You should validate the incoming parameters **before** you execute your database statements. Maybe `Request.Form["id"]` is `null` which would lead to an unexpected result similar to this one. And as a side note storing passwords in plain text in your db is very bad practice.

Comment: @jcvegan it's pointing at an input with a name "id", so what do you mean by null?

Comment: @Igor Can you please direct me to info about better ways to store a password?

Comment: There is plenty of stuff out there but here is a solution I wrote a while back for SO documents: [Complete password hashing solution using pbkdf2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/2774/hash-functions/15470/complete-password-hashing-solution-using-pbkdf2#t=201708011758539262564)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database for password storage

Comment: I have a lot to learn. Thanks @Igor!